# No puedo leer todos los números de un archivo .txt

Tags: java

Buenas estoy tratando de leer un .txt con 10 millones de números, y solo lee 5 millones y la verdad no se donde esta el problema.
Acá les dejo el código del método que estoy usando:

```
public double promedioDouble() throws IOException
    {
        double acumulador = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        try{
                file = new FileReader(ruta);
                reader = new BufferedReader(file);
                while(reader.readLine()!=null)
                {
                    acumulador+=Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
                    contador++;
                }

            }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
              System.out.println("cant read");
        }
        finally {
            if (file != null) file.close();
        }             
        return acumulador/contador;
    }
```

le hice un print al contador y solo cuenta 5 millones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fíjate que en el bucle estás haciendo dos veces `reader.readLine()`, por lo que te estás zampando las líneas de 2 en 2 en vez de 1 en 1, por eso el fichero se acaba de leer con la mitad de iteraciones que te esperabas y solo realiza la suma de las filas pares. Tendrías que hacer algo así para solucionarlo:

```
String linea;
while((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    acumulador += Double.parseDouble(linea);
    contador++;
}
```

Así solo lees una línea por iteración.

Comment: Buen hallazgo! Creería uno que quien pregunta construyó el código pensando que el primer readLines sólo validaba si había línea y después sí se movía a la siguiente.

Comment: Exactamente eso pensaba, pensaba que al estar dentro del IF solamente evaluaba la condición y seguía XD, la verdad me ayudo muchísimo ya que consulte con profesor y ninguno me supo indicar el problema, hasta que me llegaron a decir que el Buffer funcionaba mal y que utilizara scanner, pero leer 10 millones de lineas con scanner es la muerte.